# Publishing exe application

Tags: c++, c, cygwin, mingw, mingw32

I have written a code in C and C++ that uses PCRE library. To test my code I use Cygwin which contains MinGW and it works fine when I run my code from console but I get the following error when I try to install the .exe file.

> The program can't start because cygwin1.dll is missing from your computer

How can I publish .exe application that works on windows with all its dependancies?

Comment: Publish all it's dll dependencies with it. If you don't want to keep those dlls with your app, you may want to link appropriate static libraries instead.

Answer (score 0):

As it depends on cygwin1.dll is NOT a mingw program it is a cygwin one.
If you want to built a mingw program you need

1) install a cygwin to minw cross compiler; two are available depending on your arch

```
mingw64-i686-gcc
mingw64-x86_64-gcc
```

2) install the needed additional libraries, depending on your arch and the pcre release you want to use:

```
mingw64-i686-pcre
mingw64-i686-pcre2
mingw64-x86_64-pcre
mingw64-x86_64-pcre2
```

3) set your build as cross one.

Comment: I can compile and run my code from console. Now I want to deploy my code. My question is how can I publish a setup which is .exe that runs as an application.